# Symbol to use for "don't care/invalid" table/matrix entry

Tags: symbols

Is there a symbol like `\times` that can be used in mathmode to represent that an matrix element whose value does not matter. Like a small centered boldface cross.

Comment: `\times`,`\ast`,`\star`...  Have a look in the [comprehensive symbol list](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en)

Comment: `\usepackage{pifont}` and `\ding{54}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the ding 54 does a good job, but it is a bit too large so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\eleminvalid}{\ensuremath{\text{\scriptsize{\ding{54}}}}}

\begin{document}
    \[\matr{A}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & \eleminvalid\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Yes, I used \scriptsize to give it a smaller appearance

Comment: @LaRiFaRi "In two days" i will